# How do I combine different word formats in the same text box

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there any way in the same text box to have one format on 1st, 3rd, 5th line, etc...and another format on 2nd, 4th, 6th etc?
I would really like it done automatically, so for example if I copy and paste something on the 2nd line, it will continue to the 4th line etc...
Would really love to hear a reply.

Comment: Did I guess right as to your meaning of "Text Box" in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

*If by "Text Box" you mean the graphical shape entered by Insert > Text Box, ...*
You can use **styles** in your text box. One style can be defined to be followed by a different style which can be defined to be followed by the original style.

Here is [setting style for following paragraph on my website](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Following).

Here is a [sample document that demonstrates using styles like this](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#question), although not in a Text Box.

This works through the application of the styles. You need to be careful when pasting text to apply the appropriate styles. You can set keyboard shortcuts to apply styles if you want. [Topic on Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts to Styles on my website.](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Keyboard)

*If by "Text Box" you mean something else, please clarify what you do mean.*